# How do i use animation in Angular2 for Router Compoenents

Tags: animation, angular, transition

I want to animate in and out my components when the active router link changes. How do I write the code the animation code so that when the router changes, a component fades out then another fades in?

The code that I've been trying is the following.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './component.component.html',
  animations: [trigger(
    'openClose',
    [
      transition(":enter", [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate('2000ms', style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ]),
      transition(":leave", [
        animate('2000ms', style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ])]
})
```

But I think I got the concept wrong, as I'm trying to use that piece of code in at least 2 components but none of them is fading in or out.

Is this possible to do with this function or am i tackling the issue with a wrong manner?

Comment: The library for transition animations is not ready yet, but there are workarounds. See official angular github repo: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9845

Comment: This working plunker shows how to implement what you are looking for: http://plnkr.co/edit/yJHjL5ap9l4MwOimCyyY?p=preview (home.component.ts)

Comment: just an hacky way is to attach a css class to all your component ^^

Answer (score 5):

**Example with Angular 4**

Here's how I implemented a fade in animation on my home component route

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { fadeInAnimation } from '../_animations/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
    animations: [fadeInAnimation],
    host: { '[@fadeInAnimation]': '' }
})

export class HomeComponent {
}
```

This is the animation defined in a separate file

```
import { trigger, state, animate, transition, style } from '@angular/animations';

export const fadeInAnimation =
    trigger('fadeInAnimation', [
        // route 'enter' transition
        transition(':enter', [

            // styles at start of transition
            style({ opacity: 0 }),

            // animation and styles at end of transition
            animate('.3s', style({ opacity: 1 }))
        ]),
    ]);
```

For other animations and a live demo you can check out [this post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/04/19/angular-2-4-router-animation-tutorial-example)

Comment: Is there a way to make the trigger conditional within @Component? @fadeInAnimation only plays one animation (i.e. fade). I have 2 conditions: "swipe left" or "swipe right" that makes the same component animate either left (translateX 100%) or right (translateX -100%) depending on my conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems correct to me, you just need to bind the animation to a component. There are two ways:

Add it to your template, for example to a div:

```
<div class="container" [@openClose]="'true'">
   ...
</div>
```

Or directly apply it to your host component (*`<app-component>`*):

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './component.component.html',
  animations: [trigger(
    'openClose',
    [
      transition(":enter", [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate('2000ms', style({ opacity: 1 }))
      ]),
      transition(":leave", [
        animate('2000ms', style({ opacity: 0 }))
      ])
    ])],
    host: {
        '[@openClose]': 'true',
        'style': 'display: block;'
    },
})
```

**The animation works by component, so you need to declare the animation on both of them.**

The leave animation may not be noticed on state change. The official documentation has an example on [how to use animations in route components](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-animation)

Hope it helps!